# How to merge a Windows 8 install with a Linux Mint, two different disks, same computer

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot, vmware

I have Windows 8 on a disk drive that I removed from my PC. I then installed Linux Mint on a new disk drive. I would like to place the Windows 8 install, from the original disk, back on to the new disk, as dual boot... is this possible?

The problem was, I could never get my Windows 8 on the new, larger/faster disk so I basically said F*&% Windows 8 after ruining another of my weekends and loaded Mint. I can live with Mint, but I miss a few things in Windows, Photoshop and Flash Pro (for it's new convert to JavaScript tools).

Another option I thought of, but I'm scared to even try due to time constraints, is it possible to mirror the Windows install to a VM and run out of Linux... easily, or at least with a little work, reliably? That is to say, mirror the existing and not do a fresh install, because my 8 is an upgrade and now they will not let me transfer key to new install.

Comment: I am going to attempt an install of a third OS (BackTrack5) with LinuxLive USB. This I would think, can create GRUB if I select install side-by-side, right?

Comment: Btw, this worked.

Comment: Which "this" are you referring to?

Comment: @KeithThompson Installing a third Linux OS installed/set-up GRUB for me. Not exactly what I was looking for but it is close enough due to time spent already. Would be nice to get that Windows 8 on a VMWare though.

Comment: @Shane You can't virtualize a physical disk, because VMWare/Virtualbox etc creates a file format on an existing physical disk, and treats the file as a hard disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your second option, of creating a VMWare image... yes you certainly can. It is called a P2V (Physical to Virtual) migration, and you can do a hot clone, rather than a cold clone.

First, you need to put the original Windows 8 disk back into the machine. Boot it up.

Connect an external usb disk large enough to hold the Windows 8 installation, to the Windows 8 machine.

Below is an excerpt from [Converting a physical machine for Fusion, Workstation, or Player using Converter Standalone](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2005129)

**Downloading and Installing Converter**

On your physical computer, download *VMware vCenter Converter Standalone* from the [VMware Download Center](https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/info?slug=infrastructure_operations_management/vmware_vcenter_converter_standalone/5_5).

1. Double-click the installer file to start the installation.
2. Select your language.
3. Select the default installation options.
4. On the Setup Type screen, select **Local installation**.

**Converting your physical machine**

5. Start vCenter Converter.
6. Go to **File** > **New** > **Convert Machine**.
7. From the **Select source type** menu, select **Powered-on machine**.
8. Under **Specify the powered-on machine**, select **This local machine** and
   click **Next**.
9. From the **Select destination type** dropdown menu, select **VMware
   Workstation or other VMware virtual machine**.
10. From the **Select VMware product** dropdown menu, select the VMware
     product you want to use to run the virtual machine.

Note: If the current version is not available, please select the previous available version. The virtual machine can be upgraded to the latest version in the VMware Product which you are using.

11. Click **Browse** and navigate to the connected external hard drive or
         SMB network share. Choose a location on that drive to save the files
         and click **OK**.
12. If you want, change the `name` of the `virtual machine` by editing the
    Name field under Virtual machine details. Click **Next**.
13. (Optional) Click the **Edit** button beside **Data to copy** to make
     adjustments to the partitions you will import. If your computer
     only has one partition, or if you want to convert the entire disk,
     skip this step.
14. Deselect the partitions that you do not want to convert.

**Note:** If your physical machine has a recovery partition, deselect this partition.

15. Click **Next**.
16. Click **Finish** to start the conversion.

Once the conversion process has completed, disconnect the external hard drive that the converted virtual machine is stored on and connect it to the machine that is running your VMware product (Fusion, Workstation, or Player).

In your case, you will take the original Windows 8 disk back out of the machine, replace it with the larger "Mint" disk. Boot into Mint, connect the USB external disk, start up the VMWare software and point it at the virtual disk image on the USB disk (or, preferably copy the virtual disk from the USB disk to the larger mint disk) and then run the Windows 8 within Mint.

Easy!

To create a new virtual machine from the converted virtual disk files, see:

Fusion – [Creating a virtual machine from an existing virtual disk in Fusion (1023555)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1023555)
Workstation or Player – [Creating a virtual machine from a system image or another virtual machine](http://pubs.vmware.com/ws7_ace26/ws_user/newguest_ws_3.html#996821)